# Livecoin doesn't credit my balance after missing Payment ID

Tags: payment-id, exchange

I sent 0.34293098 XMR to the Livecoin Deposit address. The problem is that I used my Freewallet XMR wallet and put the Payment ID in the comment field but Livecoin says the following:

> Deposits without Payment ID, or with the wrong Payment ID, will lead to a loss of funds. About this there is a warning inscription: http://prntscr.com/h7qfl5
>   Unfortunately, we can not process your transaction, your funds are lost.
>   In next time try to fulfill the necessary conditions or refuse from risky transactions.

I know they received the XMR but they just won't lift a finger to help.
Can I do something or can you help?
Best Regards,

Marcel

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do.

Per Monero's privacy they even can't know which transaction came from you, that's why they require a payment ID. Public coins like Bitcoin let you know who send the transaction and thus do not require payment IDs. There are procedures to prove you made the payment but Livecoin won't probably loose time on that. More information about the proof of payement can be found on [Monero's Wiki](https://getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/prove-payment.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you think they made a mistake you could reveal your view key to their support so you could prove you sent the transaction. However be aware of the loss of privacy you face if you reveal your view key.